# How do I load data into a JQuery DataTables table using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, datatable

I am trying to use the DataTables JQuery plugin from datatables.net, and not having much success.

I have an MVC 5 project using Visual Studio 2013. I want to load this DataTable with JSON data, and I have been following the examples and documentation from datatables.net and am going crazy.

With the code listed below, I am getting an error in the IE debugger tools that says:

> Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
>
> File: jquery.dataTables.min.js, Line: 36, Column: 364

I am very new to all of these technologies (jquery, mvc, ajax), so if someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. I will provide any additional detail needed.

Thank you.

Here is my table:

```
<table id="deployTable" class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Unique ID</th>
        <th>Computer Name</th>
        <th>Message ID</th>
        <th>Severity</th>
        <th>Step Name</th>
        <th>Current Step</th>
        <th>Total Steps</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Last Message</th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>Dart Ticket</th>
        <th>Vm Host</th>
        <th>Vm Name</th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Task Sequence</th>
        <th>Build OU</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>            
        <th>Last Check-In</th>
        <th>Total Build Time</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Unique ID</th>
        <th>Computer Name</th>
        <th>Message ID</th>
        <th>Severity</th>
        <th>Step Name</th>
        <th>Current Step</th>
        <th>Total Steps</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Last Message</th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>Dart Ticket</th>
        <th>Vm Host</th>
        <th>Vm Name</th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Task Sequence</th>
        <th>Build OU</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>Last Check-In</th>
        <th>Total Build Time</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

          (ApplyDataTable('deployTable'));

        });
    function ApplyDataTable(tableID)
    {
        var $url = 'http://localhost:64514/Deployments/GetJson';

        $('#' + tableID).DataTable(
        {
            "ajax": $url
        });
    }
```

Here is the JSON being returned by http://localhost:64514/Deployments/GetJson

```
    [
    {
        "UniqueID": "707f8462-5a58-4036-ae8c-678ce9c08832",
        "ComputerName": "comp1",
        "MessageID": "41015",
        "Severity": "1",
        "StepName": "",
        "CurrentStep": "0",
        "TotalSteps": "0",
        "ID": "3C85167E-2D91-4074-AB10-EC9FD8FC7086,00:15:5D:50:C8:03",
        "Message": "LTI deployment completed successfully",
        "DartIP": "",
        "DartTicket": "",
        "VmHost": "vmh01",
        "VmName": "vm01",
        "Make": "Microsoft Corporation",
        "Model": "Virtual Machine",
        "UserName": "user01",
        "TaskSequenceName": "Deploy Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard",
        "OU": "",
        "StartTime": "/Date(1428512939000)/",
        "CurrentTime": "/Date(1428514813000)/",
        "BuildTime": {
            "Ticks": 18740000000,
            "Days": 0,
            "Hours": 0,
            "Milliseconds": 0,
            "Minutes": 31,
            "Seconds": 14,
            "TotalDays": 0.021689814814814815,
            "TotalHours": 0.5205555555555555,
            "TotalMilliseconds": 1874000,
            "TotalMinutes": 31.233333333333334,
            "TotalSeconds": 1874
        }
    },
    {
        "UniqueID": "0f633315-c17c-4d42-ad54-24638762843c",
        "ComputerName": "comp2",
        "MessageID": "41015",
        "Severity": "1",
        "StepName": "",
        "CurrentStep": "0",
        "TotalSteps": "0",
        "ID": "816CDE73-90FE-D511-ABDD-984BE161689E,98:4B:E1:6D:37:F8",
        "Message": "LTI deployment completed successfully",
        "DartIP": "",
        "DartTicket": "",
        "VmHost": "",
        "VmName": "",
        "Make": "HP",
        "Model": "ProLiant DL160 G6",
        "UserName": "user02",
        "TaskSequenceName": "Deploy Windows 2008 R2 Standard",
        "OU": "",
        "StartTime": "/Date(1428445762000)/",
        "CurrentTime": "/Date(1428447264000)/",
        "BuildTime": {
            "Ticks": 15020000000,
            "Days": 0,
            "Hours": 0,
            "Milliseconds": 0,
            "Minutes": 25,
            "Seconds": 2,
            "TotalDays": 0.01738425925925926,
            "TotalHours": 0.4172222222222222,
            "TotalMilliseconds": 1502000,
            "TotalMinutes": 25.033333333333335,
            "TotalSeconds": 1502
        }
    }
]
```